# Auto update Page in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and I am making a page `admin.blade.php` which will show the data of the user from the database and update automatically when the new user registered, that's not the concern. My point is to update admin page and in doing so I am using jQuery which will take data from `demo.admin.php` and update the **admin page**.

**demo.blade.php**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="result">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($users as $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $value->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->email }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**admin.blade.php**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
   $('#res').load('demo.blade.php');
  }, 100);
 });
</script>
```

**DemoController**

```
public function index()
{
    $users = DB::table('users')->select('id','name','email')->get();
    return view('demo')->with('users', $users);
}
```

**AdminController**

```
public function index()
{
    // return view('admin');
    $users = DB::table('users')->select('id','name','email')->get();
    return view('admin')->with('users', $users);
}
```

Plz, help me out. When I open admin page. the table is not showing.

Comment: You can not address this directly `$('#res').load('demo.blade.php')`. Make a route which renders this view and `load()` the corresponding path

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: You have a controller `DemoController`, so you need to address to `index()` method. `$('#res').load('/demo');` would it work ?

Comment: @user9332352 in your `web.php` create a line: `Route::get('/demo', 'DemoController@index')`. And when you go to the `/demo` it will render `demo.blade.php`

Comment: @user9332352 also you can inject your `demo.blade.php` into `admin.blade.php` by using `@yield`

Comment: Every `100 milliseconds?` Your server will implode!

Comment: Actually I was getting frustrated thats why @waterloomatt. I have changed that to 5000

Comment: Did you get it going? Do you know how to build a URL in Blade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments you can't point to a `view` because it isn't a valid URL.  jQuery's `load()` method expects a valid URL pointing to a resource. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Assuming your JS is embedded in a Blade file you can use `{{ action('DemoController@index') }}`.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
   $('#res').load('{{ action('DemoController@index') }}');
  }, 5000);
 });
</script>
```