# How to auto refresh page in laravel after certain changes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Long back i had seen my friend pass some arguments after `php artisan serve` which would basically loaded the server in the browser and whenever there is change made in any file in laravel project that get reflected by auto refreshing the page. Does anybody have any idea as to what argument needs to be passed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49392001/laravel-project-auto-refresh-after-changes something like this?

Comment: If you want to load particular blade file, check this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787107/auto-update-page-in-laravel